# Update file in Amazon S3 but keep the same url

Tags: amazon-s3, swift3

I have an app where I am uploading images to Amazon S3 service. 
I already implemented "update" flow (delete and re-add new image again).

Is there a way to update the image data, without calling delete and re-add functions each time, and update new URL?

I am using AWS iOS Swift SDK

```
//=>    Delete old profile image
if let originalImageUrl    = SessionManager.shared.curAccount?.pictureURL {
    let str                 = originalImageUrl.components(separatedBy: "/")

    let s3                  = AWSS3.default()
    let deleteRequest       = AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest()
    deleteRequest?.bucket   = Constants.AWS_S3.S3BucketName
    deleteRequest?.key      = str.last

    s3.deleteObject(deleteRequest!, completionHandler: { (s3Output, error) in
       if error != nil {
          self?.viewModel.profileOriginalImgURL.value   = originalImageUrl
       }
    })
}
```

and for Upload, something similar:

```
if let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest() {

    uploadRequest.body = urlProfileImageDir
    uploadRequest.key = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
    uploadRequest.bucket = Constants.AWS_S3.S3BucketName + "/" + Constants.AWS_S3.FolderProfileImages
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/" + ext

    if let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default() {
        transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continue({ (task) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error {
.....
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "keep the same url"? When you send files to s3, you get to choose what URL the file is accessible through.

Comment: @GregHewgill I just want to update the metadata of that url. In basic words: "update image for specific url". Thanks

Comment: Can you describe how you're implementing this?  Is there a server component?  If not, which development kit are you using?  At a generic level, the PutObject method will "update" if the key already exists.  If the key is the same then, assuming you mean static S3 hosting, the URL will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how AWS iOS Swift SDK works, but you can just upload the image with the same name, it will update the old version, and keeping the same URL.